Removing vertices from rooted tree to make it balanced
The question says, what is the least number of vertices that must be deleted from T to yield a balanced tree. The correct answer is 1. But how, i see the graph is already balanced and doesn’t need removing anything. Could someone please explain.
Tree graph

What is a balanced tree?

A tree that has m-ary?
